# How to implement custom @Enable annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've created annotation **@EnableMyConfiguration**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Import(MyConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableMyConfiguration{
}
```

And created simple configuration

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public String testStringBean() {
        String s = "Hello world";
        log.info("TeST LOG = {}", s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Dependencies in pom.xml for this library:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.2.RELEASE

I've tried to use this starter in my test project
This project has following dependencies:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.1.RELEASE
- dependency with my library

And in Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMyConfiguration
public class MainTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

But it is not worked. My bean is not created. Could you please help me? What I could lose ?

Comment: I really dont understand what you are trying to do? Yes you got the custom annotation but then you are importing the Configuration class into it? Why? You don't import things into annotation you put annotation over things that you want to add additional behavior to. And what bean? Method that is not annotated as a bean is not a bean

Comment: Just create a custom annotation (without imports) and then annotate with it a method that you want additional behavior for, and then use Spring AOP to add additional behaviour, example https://medium.com/@ashrithgn/custom-annotation-to-handle-authorisation-in-spring-boot-46e69df6baf3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your library application has the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` enabled:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you're using gradle, use the gradle equivalent.

Everything you have so far is correct on the java end.